# Insert new-line character at string midpoint while respecting word boundaries

Tags: r, regex

I have strings like these:

```
strings <- 
c("((m: points outward with right thumb, beat on \"Hauptbahnhof\"))", 
"((m: both h kept palm down at chest height, slight beat on \"train station\"))", 
"((m: both hands, first right then left, rotate around wrist))", 
"((m: left h held laterally at knee height))", "((m & f: both h held above knee palms down, mouth wide open))", 
"((m: left h remains above knee while right h palm inward repeats shoving movement))", 
"((m: both h palm open held above knee with slight beat twice))", 
"((m: both h palms toward each other meet in triangular shape above thigh))", 
"((m: both h palms inward at chest height make slight outward movement))", 
"((m & t & f: in sudden move, torso slightly forward, mouth wide open, both h stretch out, palms facing outward))", 
"((m & f: blank stare, both arms stretched, both h palms down held above knee))", 
"((m: r hand resting on knee, l hand palm down pushes down))", 
"((m: both arms stretched, both h palms down, turns r hand on \"down\"))", 
"((m: r hand palm down sweeps laterally on \"already\"))")
```

I'd like to insert the new-line character `\n` at the strings' midpoint, measured in number of characters. Where that midpoint falls *into* a word, `\n` should be inserted at the prior left-hand word boundary.

I'm not highly successful with what I've tried so far. Establishing the midpoint works okay:

```
midpoint <- round(str_count(strings, "")/2,0)
[1] 31 38 30 22 30 42 31 37 36 56 39 30 34 26
```

But inserting `\n` at that point already runs into trouble:

```
gsub(paste0("(.{", midpoint, "})(.*)$"), "\\1\n\\2", strings)
 [1] "((m: points outward with right \nthumb, beat on \"Hauptbahnhof\"))"                                                
 [2] "((m: both h kept palm down at c\nhest height, slight beat on \"train station\"))"                                  
 [3] "((m: both hands, first right th\nen left, rotate around wrist))"                                                   
 [4] "((m: left h held laterally at k\nnee height))"                                                                     
 [5] "((m & f: both h held above knee\n palms down, mouth wide open))"                                                   
 [6] "((m: left h remains above knee \nwhile right h palm inward repeats shoving movement))"                             
 [7] "((m: both h palm open held abov\ne knee with slight beat twice))"                                                  
 [8] "((m: both h palms toward each o\nther meet in triangular shape above thigh))"                                      
 [9] "((m: both h palms inward at che\nst height make slight outward movement))"                                         
[10] "((m & t & f: in sudden move, to\nrso slightly forward, mouth wide open, both h stretch out, palms facing outward))"
[11] "((m & f: blank stare, both arms\n stretched, both h palms down held above knee))"                                  
[12] "((m: r hand resting on knee, l \nhand palm down pushes down))"                                                     
[13] "((m: both arms stretched, both \nh palms down, turns r hand on \"down\"))"                                         
[14] "((m: r hand palm down sweeps la\nterally on \"already\"))"                                                         
Warning message:
In gsub(paste0("(.{", midpoint, "})(.*)$"), "\\1\n\\2", strings) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

The warning suggests that only the first pattern element has been used. Also, not surprisingly, word boundaries have not been respected. How can I more successfully insert `\n` at string midpoints and move that insertion point backward to the last word boundary if the point falls into a word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mapply` and add `\\b.*`:

```
midpoint <- nchar(strings) %/% 2
mapply(sub, paste0("(.*)(\\b.*.{", midpoint, "})$"), "\\1\n\\2", strings, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
# [1] "((m: points outward with right \nthumb, beat on \"Hauptbahnhof\"))"                                                
# [2] "((m: both h kept palm down at chest \nheight, slight beat on \"train station\"))"                                  
# [3] "((m: both hands, first right \nthen left, rotate around wrist))"                                                   
# [4] "((m: left h held \nlaterally at knee height))"                                                                     
# [5] "((m & f: both h held above knee\n palms down, mouth wide open))"                                                   
# [6] "((m: left h remains above knee while right\n h palm inward repeats shoving movement))"                             
# [7] "((m: both h palm open held \nabove knee with slight beat twice))"                                                  
# [8] "((m: both h palms toward each other \nmeet in triangular shape above thigh))"                                      
# [9] "((m: both h palms inward at chest \nheight make slight outward movement))"                                         
#[10] "((m & t & f: in sudden move, torso slightly forward, \nmouth wide open, both h stretch out, palms facing outward))"
#[11] "((m & f: blank stare, both arms \nstretched, both h palms down held above knee))"                                  
#[12] "((m: r hand resting on knee, l\n hand palm down pushes down))"                                                     
#[13] "((m: both arms stretched, both h \npalms down, turns r hand on \"down\"))"                                         
#[14] "((m: r hand palm down \nsweeps laterally on \"already\"))"
```

Comment: `?mapply` gives: *USE.NAMES: logical; use names if the first ... argument has names, or if it is a character vector, use that character vector as the names.*

Answer (score 1):

A bit more clunky, however a bit more explicit:

```
a = "((m: both h palms toward each other meet in triangular shape above thigh))"
center = nchar(a) / 2
centerChar = substr(a, center, center)

while (regexpr('[\n \r]', centerChar)[1] == -1) {
  center = center - 1
  centerChar = substr(a, center, center)    
}

part_one = substr(a, 0, center)
part_two = substr(a, center + 1, nchar(a))
print(part_one)
print(part_two)
print(paste(part_one, part_two, sep='\n'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a function recursively to find the previous word boundary, and then use one of the `*apply` functions for the `sub` call:

```
midpoint_space <- function(string) {
  midpoint <- nchar(string) %/% 2
  if (substr(string, midpoint, midpoint) == " ") {
    nchar(string) %/% 2
  } else {
    midpoint_space(substr(string, 1, nchar(string) - 1))
  }
}
    
midpoint <- sapply(strings, midpoint_space, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
    
sapply(seq_along(strings), function(i) {
  gsub(paste0("(.{", midpoint[i], "})(.*)$"), "\\1\n\\2", strings[i])
})
```